# Border Hovering

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I've been trying to fix my HTML code, and encountered an issue.
My goal is that the button will be cover the entire element, I found the solution but my solution is making the border hover, not sure how to fix.

```css
.butn {
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #ffeaa7;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  Font-size: 20px;
}

.butn:hover {
  background-color: #7bed9f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="listdrop">
  <li class="card-head">Intermidate</li>

  <li>Get Big</li>
  <li>Get Strong</li>
  <li>Feel good</li>
  <li class="pay">300$</li>
  <li class="butn">
    <button type="button" class="butn">Buy</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I will post my code pen code as well : https://codepen.io/picklemyrickle/pen/XWjzyvb
so again my goal is to make sure the button covers the entire block, like in the "casual" + "beginner" buttons(The HTML is wrong there), the solution I've done on "Intermidate" works, but if you put the mouse on the border of that button, it hovers the edges, not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

So from looking at the codepen, it seems like all three act the same. From what I gather, you want to make the entire element clickable. Now you can encapsulate everything else in a button but that might get messy.

Alternatively, you can also use the on-click event on the lists and then in CSS add:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

By inspection, it would look exactly as if it were a button but semantically it would be different.

Comment: Hi, if you take a look at the "Intermidate button" the edges hover, because I changed the html on it. How I remove the hover from the edges? I understand it has something to do with class="butn", but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Do you mean that the "intermediate button" is bigger? The hover animation is exactly the same between the three.

EDIT: I took a look at why it's bigger, it is because you have 
```
<li class="butn">
    <button type="button" class="butn">Buy</button>
       </li>
```

Comment: No, the bigger isn't the issue. Unfortunately if you open it from a mobile device it looks the same. But if you try on your pc and hover your mouse on the edges of the Intermediate button, you will see the edges hover and I don't know why.

Comment: Please send a screenshot. I don't see the hovering effect. If it's the dropdown shadow, it is because of .listdrop:hover{box-shadow: 0 8px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4S52Xvm

https://i.imgur.com/TDAJ1fe.png

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3tK4JMq
The codepen you provided does not even address your issue. Let me know when the codepen addresses your problem and I'll look at this again.

Comment: once I add the <li> code to the button it creates the issue :
       <li class="butn">
    <button type="button" class="butn">Buy</button>
       </li>
when I remove it, there is no hover on the edges, don't you see it from my picture? It can't be from my pc only.. I am not sure how you can't see it. Have you put your mouse over the edges? Anyway I am not sure why it creates this issue..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class="butn" from the `<li>`, then the border will be gone (leave it only inside the button):

`<li><button type="button" class="butn">Buy</button></li>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried doing it wasn't working.
I retyped display: block, on butn class, and it seems to be working now.
Thanks anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty simple:

```
.butn {
display: block;
width: 100%;
}
```

for some reason I had display:block; already and it didn't work I don't know why, I retyped it and it worked.